# Error in getting Memory Usage of Application

Tags: c++, syntax, struct, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use this piece of code to get the memory usage of my application. However, I get the following error when I try to compile:

`error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token`

Here is my code:

```
#include "sys/types.h
#include "sys/sysinfo.h

using namespace std;
struct sysinfo memInfo;
sysinfo (& memInfo);
```

Comment: Why don't the quotations close in the `#include` directives? That might be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you left out significant parts of your code, ut seems you try to call `sysinfo(&meminfo)` at namespace scope. However, you can't have a function call statement at namespace scope. Try moving the code into a function, e.g.:

```
int main() {
    struct sysinfo meminfo;
    sysinfo(&meminfo);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know it's a pretty dumb question, but I'm still not used to C++. Sorry.